# How to handle spanish characters in the json localization file

Tags: mvvmcross

Im localizing my App to spanish, and I notice that all the spanish especific characters (ñ, á, í, ó, ú) are show like a question mark (?) instead of the letter, for example: I get the text "acci?n" instead of "acción". I guess it´s an encoding issue while reading the json file (the plugins doesnt recognize those characters).

Is this a bug? or I have to specify the encoding in some place?

Thanks in advance

Roygar

Comment: I'm currently working on a Danish project and characters like æ and é work fine there in Touch and Droid. Perhaps you could include some more information like which platforms you are on, which devices you are testing with, which encoding you are using for your json files, etc. The json parsing itself uses Newtonsoft.Json - so you also should be able to quiet quickly parse these files in a test app - does the parsing look ok in these?

Comment: Hi Stuart, so far I've only tested on WPF (Windows Store will be next). Maybe this will be a really stupid question, but where o how do I set the encoding of the json localization file??. I opened the file with visual studio, notepad, chrome and all the characters are fine, just the App shows them wrong.

Comment: I just changed the Wpf sample in https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross-Tutorials/tree/master/Babel to include accented characters - it worked - http://i.imgur.com/Lksrx5B.png - maybe try that example in your environment and see if you can get it working.

Comment: Uhmm.. weird, the Babel simple shows the right text in wpf... I guess I'll have to do more tests... I'll let you know if I found something.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, Finally I solved the issue, I'm posting the answer in case anybody has the same problem in the future..

The problem was the encoding Visual Studio 2013 for the json file . When I added the file and opened with the default editor I couldn't see the encoding in the properties, but when using the option "Open with... " (right click over the file) and selected the "XML Text Editor" I could right click inside the file, select properties and see the encoding being used (in my case was "European Western (Windows)), simply changing the value to Unicode and saving the file solved all the problems with special characters..

I dont know why VS 2013 was setting that encoding, but at least I found the way to fix it...

Thanks Stuart for your comments and support..